# Return a Cell from a Pandas Dataframe based on other values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataset in a Pandas Dataframe:

| Id | Year | Month | Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 2020 | 9 | 11788.33 |
| 1 | 2020 | 10 | 18373.99 |
| 2 | 2020 | 11 | 31018.59 |
| 3 | 2020 | 12 | 29279.30 |
| 4 | 2021 | 1 | 1875.10 |
| 5 | 2021 | 2 | 9550.06 |
| 6 | 2021 | 3 | 33844.39 |
| 7 | 2021 | 4 | 33126.53 |
| 8 | 2021 | 5 | 12910.05 |
| 9 | 2021 | 6 | 44628.63 |
| 10 | 2021 | 7 | 25830.03 |
| 11 | 2021 | 8 | 54463.08 |
| 12 | 2021 | 9 | 49723.93 |
| 13 | 2021 | 10 | 23753.81 |
| 14 | 2021 | 11 | 52532.49 |
| 15 | 2021 | 12 | 7467.32 |
| 16 | 2022 | 1 | 24333.54 |
| 17 | 2022 | 2 | 12394.11 |
| 18 | 2022 | 3 | 76575.46 |
| 19 | 2022 | 4 | 95119.82 |
| 20 | 2022 | 5 | 63048.05 |

I am trying to dynamically return the value from the **Total** column based on the **first month** (Month 1) from **last year** (Year 2021). Solution is 1875.10.

I am using Python in PyCharm to complete this.

Note: The "Id" column is the one that is automatically generated when using a pandas Dataframe. I believe it is called an index within Pandas.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`.loc[]`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
df.loc[(df['Year'] == 2021) & (df['Month'] == 1), 'Total']
```

Which will give you:

```
0    1875.1
Name: Total, dtype: float64
```

To get the actual number you can add [`.iloc[]`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) on the end:

```
df.loc[(df['Year'] == 2021) & (df['Month'] == 1), 'Total'].iloc[0]
```

Output:

```
1875.1
```

Comment: thank you! I was looking for that within the Pandas library and couldn't seem to put all that together.

Answer (score 1):

Another method is doing this.

```
df[df['Year']==2021].iloc[0]['Total']
```

This part  `df[df['Year']==2021]` creates a new dataframe, where we only have values from 2021, and the .iloc fetches the value at position 0 in the 'Total' column

Comment: thanks for sharing this with me! I actually really like this approach. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Would simple filter suffice?

```py
df[(df.Year == 2021) & (df.Month == 1)].Total
```

Comment: thank you! I am new to Python and still learning a lot. That was really helpful. The result set is giving me the solution but also the column name and data type. Is there a way to prevent that and just return the number?

Comment: yeah something like:
`df[(df.Year == 2021) & (df.Month == 1)].Total.iloc[0]`. 

This assumes after filtering you end up with a single row, and take the value of the 1st element of that row (that is index 0 in python). 

If in the future your after filtering you end up with more then one row, the above code will return the first element of the Series.